# Ansible item regex issue

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-facts

i'm trying to automatically collect the exe file related to a core file, the regex works as shown from DEBUG ExeFileList output, but the "Adding the exe to the archive..." fails, any ideas?

#example line of ExeFileList.results[0]['stdout_lines']: /home/user/test/core.12786: ELF 32-bit LSB core file Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from 'ESSRTR55-102548'

```
  - name: DEBUG ExeFileList
    debug:
      msg: "{{item | regex_search(\"(?<=\')(.*?)(?=\')\") }}" 
    loop: "{{ ExeFileList.results[0]['stdout_lines']  }}"

    TASK [DEBUG ExeFileList] ***********************************************************
    task path: /home/XXXXXXXX/Documents/Repos/AnsibleXX/CollectLogs.yml:43
    ok: [gw4ank] => (item=/home/user/test/core.12786: ELF 32-bit LSB core file Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from 'ESSRTR55-102548') => {
        "msg": "ESSRTR55-102548"
    }
```

this work as expected, but the next one..

```
  - name: Adding the exe to the archive...
    raw: find /home/user/test -name {{ item | regex_search(\"(?<=\')(.*?)(?=\')\") }} -type f -mtime -{{days}} -exec tar -rvf /tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}.logs.tar "{}" \;
    loop: "{{ ExeFileList.results[0]['stdout_lines'] }}"
```

The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/XXXXXXXX/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 504, in _execute
    self._task.post_validate(templar=templar)
  File "/home/XXXXXXXX/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/playbook/task.py", line 308, in post_validate
    super(Task, self).post_validate(templar)
  File "/home/XXXXXXXX/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/playbook/base.py", line 431, in post_validate
    value = templar.template(getattr(self, name))
  File "/home/XXXXXXXX/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 878, in template
    disable_lookups=disable_lookups,
  File "/home/XXXXXXXX/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 833, in template
    disable_lookups=disable_lookups,
  File "/home/XXXXXXXX/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 1076, in do_template
    data = _escape_backslashes(data, myenv)
  File "/home/XXXXXXXX/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 165, in _escape_backslashes
    for token in jinja_env.lex(d2):
  File "/home/XXXXXXXX/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/lexer.py", line 868, in tokeniter
    f"unexpected char {source[pos]!r} at {pos}", lineno, name, filename
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '\\' at 73
  line 1
failed: [sr1rmn] (item=/home/user/test/core.12786: ELF 32-bit LSB core file Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from 'ESSRTR55-102548') => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "/home/user/test/core.12786: ELF 32-bit LSB core file Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from 'ESSRTR55-102548'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding "" and escapes .
This:

```
raw: find /home/user/test -name {{ item | regex_search(\"(?<=\')(.*?)(?=\')\") }} -type f -mtime -{{days}} -exec tar -rvf /tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}.logs.tar "{}" \;
```

to this:

```
raw: "find /home/user/test -name \"{{ item | regex_search(\"(?<=\')(.*?)(?=\')\") }}*\" -type f -mtime -{{days}} -exec tar -rvf /tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}.logs.tar \"{}\" \\;"
```

Comment: Escape your backlash on command. Notes: using raw is evil. At the very least use shell/command. You have a find and archive module that can do this job.